# Crash after splashscreen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, splash-screen

i'm new at android studio and i'm developing my first app.

Everything worked fine until i implemented a splashscreen. Indeed, when i run the app, the splashcreen works, but then, it crashes.

The thing is that the splashscreen wasn't the first activity i've created (the main). I've created my app and when i finished it, i added a splashscreen.

Actually when i disable the splashscreen (the activity) and start directly with the previous "activity that appears on launch" (that is the "Menu"), it works fine.

And one weird thing: with the splashscreen enabled, it crashes only with certain devices. It runs perfectly with my Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 and a Galaxy S4 (or the nexus 5X emulator) but not with a Galaxy S3 and S6 .

I tried to replace the timer by a simple setonclicklistener button. But same, when it has to load the Menu, it crashes.

I haven't find similar problems on the forums so here i am !

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Menu"/>
    <activity android:name=".restaurant" />
    <activity android:name=".courses" />
    <activity android:name=".toilettes" />
    <activity android:name=".distributeur" />
    <activity android:name=".essence" />
    <activity android:name=".hopital" />
    <activity android:name=".Splashscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>


    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

Here is the Splashscreen -java

```
package fr.libertyg.messervices;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;

public class Splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView daccord;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

    final TextView random = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random);
    final String[] mesphrases = {"S1", "S2",
            "S3", "S4", "S5","S6"};
    int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    random.setText(mesphrases[rando]);

    this.daccord = findViewById(R.id.daccord);
    daccord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent otheractivity = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(otheractivity);
            finish();


        }
    });






}
```

The Splashscreen xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Splashscreen"
android:weightSum="10"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/splashscreenfond">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spashscreenbienvenue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/splashscreenbienvenue"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="217dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonasavoir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/bonasavoir"
        android:textSize="17sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/donnees"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/random"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/activezgps"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/random"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:text="Un être humain a besoin d'environ 2000 kcal/jour"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/version" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/daccord"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/daccord" />
</RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

And the Menu -java

```
package fr.libertyg.messervices;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView distributeur;
private ImageView restaurant;
private ImageView courses;
private ImageView toilettes;
private ImageView essence;
private ImageView hopital;
AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    this.distributeur = findViewById(R.id.distributeur);

    distributeur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent otherActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), distributeur.class);
            startActivity(otherActivity);

        }
    });

    this.restaurant = findViewById(R.id.restaurant);

    restaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent otherActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), restaurant.class);
            startActivity(otherActivity);

        }
    });

    this.courses = findViewById(R.id.courses);

    courses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent otherActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), courses.class);
            startActivity(otherActivity);

        }
    });

    this.toilettes = findViewById(R.id.toilettes);

    toilettes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent otherActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), toilettes.class);
            startActivity(otherActivity);

        }
    });

    this.essence = findViewById(R.id.essence);

    essence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent otherActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), essence.class);
            startActivity(otherActivity);

        }
    });

    this.hopital = findViewById(R.id.hopital);

    hopital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent otherActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), hopital.class);
            startActivity(otherActivity);

        }
    });

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-6520930039267956~4038950000");
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);









}

}
```

And the Menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/fond"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bienvenue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/quoi"
        android:textColor="@color/blanc"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7.6">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/distributeur"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:src="@drawable/distributeur" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/restaurant"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/courses"
        top="@+id/distributeur"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/distributeur"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/courses" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toilettes"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/restaurant"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/courses"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/toilettes" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/essence"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/distributeur"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/essence" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hopital"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/restaurant"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/essence"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/hopital" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6520930039267956/3068657000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks by advance for helping me.

Comment: Please post a stacktrace

Comment: Posted the Logcat, if it's what you need. 

Thanks.

Comment: I dont have an answer for you, but, I can tell you that for some reason the sdk cant find the following class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener". This might be happening because of instant run, so try to clean and rebuild. Or it might be something else entirely. Sorry couldnt help more.

Comment: Ok, no problem, thanks anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your app gradle make sure that libs use the same version, like:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

You probably don't need all of them.  
Make the changes and then click "Sync Now"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

I had to add this to the manifest:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

And it worked fine.